# python - how do I transfer values from one df to another

Tags: python, pandas, merge

These are the two dfs

```
Rating = ['A', 'AAA', 'AA', 'BBB', 'BB', 'B']
val = [4560.0, 64.0, 456.0, 34.0, 534.0, 54.0]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(Rating,val)),index=[0]).T
df.columns = ['values']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['AA','AA','AA','AA','A','A'],columns=['Rating'])
df1.set_index('Rating',inplace=True)
df1 = df1.merge(df,left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

I used merge which work, but problem is it doesnt preserve the sequence of my original df1 dataFrame

```
df1 = df1.merge(df,left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

How can I run merge and preserve the sequence as well?

edited################

I get this output
[image]

I want the sequencing to be what was in the original df i.e. ['AA','AA','AA','AA','A','A']

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the output is supposed to look like

Comment: added in the original body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Rating' : ['A', 'AAA', 'AA', 'BBB', 'BB', 'B'],
    'val' : [4560.0, 64.0, 456.0, 34.0, 534.0, 54.0]
})
df
###
  Rating     val
0      A  4560.0
1    AAA    64.0
2     AA   456.0
3    BBB    34.0
4     BB   534.0
5      B    54.0
```

Keeping `df1` as yours, but don't `set_index()` additionally.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['AA','AA','AA','AA','A','A'],columns=['Rating'])
df1
###
  Rating
0     AA
1     AA
2     AA
3     AA
4      A
5      A
```

Doing the `merge()`

```
df1 = df1.merge(df,left_on='Rating', right_on='Rating')
df1
###
  Rating     val
0     AA   456.0
1     AA   456.0
2     AA   456.0
3     AA   456.0
4      A  4560.0
5      A  4560.0
```

Then `set_index()`

```
df1.set_index('Rating', inplace=True)
df1
###
           val
Rating        
AA       456.0
AA       456.0
AA       456.0
AA       456.0
A       4560.0
A       4560.0
```

---

#### With different `df1`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['AA', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AA', 'AA'], columns=['Rating'])
df1
###
  Rating
0     AA
1      A
2      A
3      A
4     AA
5     AA
```

Doing the `merge()`

```
df1 = df1.merge(df,left_on='Rating', right_on='Rating', how='left')
df1
###
  Rating     val
0     AA   456.0
1      A  4560.0
2      A  4560.0
3      A  4560.0
4     AA   456.0
5     AA   456.0
```

Comment: if you replace df1 with this do you get correct answer? df1 = pd.DataFrame(['AA', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AA', 'AA'], columns=['Rating'])

Comment: I am not, whats why asking

Comment: Then you have to use `df1 = df1.merge(df,left_on='Rating', right_on='Rating', how='left')` with `how='left'`

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you can use `sort_index()` after the merging:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df,left_index=True,right_index=True).sort_index(ascending=False)
```

Returns:

```
    values
AA   456.0
AA   456.0
AA   456.0
AA   456.0
A   4560.0
A   4560.0
```

Comment: no but I want it to be generic i.e what if i change df1 to df1 = pd.DataFrame(['AA','A','A','AA','AA','AA'],columns=['Rating'])